# Convert IFormFile to Image in Asp Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i need to resize file upload if file is image .

i write the extention for resize that :

```
 public static Image ResizeImage(this Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        var res = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(res))
        {
            graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and this is `Upload Action :`

```
 [HttpPost("UploadNewsPic"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public IActionResult UploadNewsPic(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file.IsImage())
        {

        }
        try
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(_applicationRoot.UploadNewPath(), file.Name);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

**now my problem is here =>** my extention just work on type of `Image` file but type of this file is `IFormFile` . how can i convert the `IFormFile` to `Image` type ?

Comment: You could put the IFormFile into a byte/memory stream and create the BMP from there.

Comment: @JohnB `System.Drawing` exists in .NET Core. It was ported for 2.1 and is available since then.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use the `Image.FromStream()` method to read the stream as an Image:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
                {
                  // TODO: ResizeImage(img, 100, 100);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do what frameworks does this apply? I cannot find the method `FromStream`.

Comment: You need this package for it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/

Comment: Thanks, found it yesterday :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to open file using OpenReadStream and convert into image format. And pass the same to your extension method.

```
FileDetails fileDetails;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                   var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                   var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
                   fileDetails = new FileDetails
                      {
                          Filename = parsedContentDisposition.FileName,
                          Content = fileContent,
                          ContentType=file.ContentType
                       };
                 }
```

Comment: what is the `FileDetails` ??

Comment: Create a custom class, you can add into ViewModel to keep the filedata.