# How to Resize IFormFile using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I upload an image from Customer, and I want to resize it being an IFormFileCollection item. I tried to use **System.Drawing**, **Veldrid,ImageSharp** and other ways from StackOverFlow issues but none works fine.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: "and other ways from StackOverFlow issues but none works fine." - why aren't they working for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161001/convert-iformfile-to-image-in-asp-core For example => "Image.FromStream()" This method does not exists in Image Class, neither "file.IsImage()"...

Comment: @JesusHedo, it is there, it is visible when you assign it to some variable

Comment: It's not visible when I assign it to a variable