# Create thumbnail in c# from stream

Tags: c#, image

After 3 hours of debugging and searching I have this.

```cs
        public Stream ResizeImageToThumbnail(Stream imageStream, int width)
        {
            var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);

            var height = (width * image.Height) / image.Width;
            var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            using var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream();
            thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return thumbnailStream;
        }
```

Problem is, it returns exception

> ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

at

```
var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
```

Parameter is `file.OpenFileStream();` where `file` is `IFormFile`.

I'm out of ideas.

Edit

Requested code:

```cs
foreach (var item in model.UploadedImages) //item = IFormFile, image only allowed from HTML's end
{
   using var ms = item.OpenReadStream();
   _service.AttachImage(newId, ms, item.FileName);
   ms.Position = 0;
   _service.AttachThumb(newId, ms, item.FileName); //cannot access a closed stream exception
}
```

Edit 2

AttachThumb is using closed stream, returns exception (check comment). It appears that `ResizeImageToThumbnail` returns closed stream.

```cs
public void AttachThumb(Guid id, Stream imageStream, string imageName)
        {
            Post post = GetPost(id);

            ObjectId imageId = _gridFS.UploadFromStream(imageName, ResizeImageToThumbnail(imageStream, 640)); //cannot use closed stream

            post.ImagesThumbs.Add(imageId.ToString());

            var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
            var update = Builders<Post>.Update.Set("ImagesThumbs", post.ImagesThumbs);
            _posts.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        }

        public Stream ResizeImageToThumbnail(Stream imageStream, int width)
        {
            var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);

            var height = (width * image.Height) / image.Width;
            var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            using var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream();
            thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return thumbnailStream;
        }
```

Comment: Store the file to disc to check whether it is a valid image file. What image file is it?

Comment: @NineBerry its jpg. When I dump it directly to database it works fine. But displaying such huge file as thumbnail is bad idea.

Comment: Open Image with note pad.  The image should have a ASCII header showing type of image.  The image may not be compatible with the graphic card.  Another possibility is the stream is a Base64 stream and need to be converted to bytes.

Comment: Try copy from IFormFile to MemoryStream, Then create Image from MemoryStream. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161871/5045688

Comment: Do you try to access the same uploaded file as a stream twice? If yes, you need to rewind the stream in between by setting its position property to 0.

Comment: @NineBerry yes, but then I get exception that stream is closed. So I create 2 copies of stream (var stream1, var stream2), and use it accordingly.

Comment: How do you create and fill those two streams? The second one is empty of you don't and can't rewind in between. Make the second stream copying the content from the first

Comment: @NineBerry now it returns `ObjectDisposedException`. `ResizeImageToThumbnail` is the second function called. First saves original to database. That part works fine. 2nd part either saves corrupted file, or returns exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy the content of the file into a stream, then use that stream. Rewind the stream in between. Note that the two Attach* methods must not access the stream asynchronously. Otherwise you would have to create a second in-memory copy first.

```
foreach (var item in model.UploadedImages)
{
    // Copy content in to stream
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        item.CopyTo(stream);

        // Rewind and use
        stream.Position = 0;
        _service.AttachImage(newId, stream, item.FileName);
        
        // Rewind and use
        stream.Position = 0;
        _service.AttachThumb(newId, stream, item.FileName);
    }
}
```

---

As noted by user Jimi, you have to remove the `using` clause from the `ResizeImageToThumbnail` method. Otherwise the method returns an already disposed `MemoryStream`:

```
public Stream ResizeImageToThumbnail(Stream imageStream, int width)
{
    var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);

    var height = (width * image.Height) / image.Width;
    var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Bad: using var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream();
    // Remove using
    var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream(); 
    thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return thumbnailStream;
}
```

Then dispose the stream outside:

```
public void AttachThumb(Guid id, Stream imageStream, string imageName)
{
    Post post = GetPost(id);

    using var thumbnailStream = ResizeImageToThumbnail(imageStream, 640);
    // rewind stream
    thumbnailStream.position = 0;
    ObjectId imageId = _gridFS.UploadFromStream(imageName, thumbnailStream); 

    ...
```

---

You could improve the design of this by not having the `ResizeImageToThumbnail` method create the stream but instead create the stream outside and pass it to `ResizeImageToThumbnail` as a parameter. So the caller of `ResizeImageToThumbnail` is then responsible for creating and disposing the stream.

Comment: Still broken. But I know what is. Made an edit.

Comment: Figured it out. But I don't know how to convince compiler to not dispose it.

Comment: Just remove the keyword `using`  within the ResizeImageToThumbnail method.

Comment: Ok, so half of the problem is solved (thank you). But thumbnail is still corrupted. Full sized image is displaying, thumbnail displays just "no image" icon.

Comment: You might have to rewind the stream before giving it to `_gridFS.UploadFromStream()`.  I updated my answer. Working with streams means always being aware that they have a current position. And you need to rewind that position regularly if you want to work with all their content

Comment: Finally. C# is really simple, but this looks like something stolen from C or C++. Took only 5 hours, but you saved me probably another 10 hours. Thanks for help.

Comment: @HPotts3 "but this looks like something stolen from C or C++" That's because it is. All of `System.Drawing` is just a wrapper around the Windows GDI+ system. It's not a native .Net system.